# Validate Call SID

Tags: php, validation, rest, twilio

In my DB I have such call SID that do not exist in Twilio. It is another questions why, but it is a fact.

The following code:

```
    $call = $client->account->calls->get(
        'YYYYYYYYYYYY7'
    );

    var_dump($call->price);
```

Throws:

```
Services_Twilio_RestException

The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/YYYYYYYYYYYY7.json was not found
```

But the following code:

```
    $call = $client->account->calls->get(
        'YYYYYYYYYYYY7'
    );

    var_dump($call->sid);
```

Works fine:

```
string(34) "CAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY7"
```

If I take valid call SID, and do this:

```
    $call = $client->account->calls->get(
        'CASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS'
    );

    var_dump(isset($call->price));
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump(!empty($call->duration));
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump($call->price);
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump($call->duration);
```

I will get this:

```
bool(false) 
bool(false) 
string(8) "-0.01400" 
string(2) "32"
```

**Problem**

Twilio SDK is written so, that there is actually no  way to check that call item has certain attribute before your code fails.

Proper code should be ready to handle such situations when some call (or anything else) might not exist.

So I have a question: How can I validate Call SID **using Twilio PHP SDK** ?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install

**P.S.**

Of course I did

```
    function validateCallSID($callsid) {
        $ch = curl_init("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" .  TWILIO_SID . "/Calls/" . $callsid . ".json");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, TWILIO_SID);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, TWILIO_ST);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!empty($json)) {
            $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
            if (!empty($decoded['sid'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I am sure that Twilio SDK developed by such big company as Twilio of course should have a build-in way to do it, but I simply have not noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio libraries are all built to be dynamic, based on the attributes returned from the array, and lazy, so that you don't make an API call until you need to. That explains why `isset($call->price)` [property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) returns `false` but then has a value.

I am intrigued by the call SID that didn't have a price though, would you mind sending it to philnash@twilio.com so I can take a look at what is going on there. I can take a look into fixing the error message from the API, as it's not a 404 as you showed.

Comment: How can i check $call->sid is valid or not ?

Comment: What do you mean? All call objects returned from the API will have a `sid`.